# Mule ESB & PING Identity Integration

Tags: mule, ping, saml

I am trying to set up SSO between Mule and PING Identity and get the SAML Assertion. Once i get the assertion I can make calls to Salesforce for other process. If anyone could give any pointers on how to integrate Mule and PING Identity it would be great! I didnt find any uses cases or demo in Mule form either.

Comment: Did you check https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/SAML+Module ?

Comment: @DavidDossot :( I did check that that didn't mention how I need to pass the user parameters to the IDP and receive the SAML Assertion. the document talks about after receiving the SAML assertion how to make calls to webservice for authentication.

Comment: :'( This is an Enterprise Edition feature: try contacting MuleSoft professional support?

Comment: @DavidDossot thanks david. yup i did that. Hopefully i can write an answer to this question once i complete it :)